# Integrating Pentaho Community dashboards into custom java application

Tags: pentaho

We need to build a custom java web application that can display dashboards from Pentaho Community edition.  The application will be written in the Play Framework (Java/Scala) and will use single sign on (and we cannot use Spring Security for reasons that are not relevant here.)

So we want our custom application, which has several custom UI's, to also seamlessly display dashboards, once the end user has logged in using the authentication method used by the customer.

We want our customer's analysts, who are good with computers but not programmers, to be trained on the dashboard builder so that they can modify and add elements to dashboards after we have delivered this application.  So we want the app to be self-service (no Java coding, just maybe some SQL) for the end-users after we the developers are gone.

This all needs to be under the Community Edition.

Is this possible?  If so, which API would you recommend that we use to build a prototype?  The documentation was not clear to me about this.

Thanks!

Comment: As a developer using iframe you can open pentaho in your java application. and once you will do this create dashboards according to client requirement and give it to them. they will required to do any changes after words.

Comment: Thanks, but does that allow us to protect the pentaho server with credentials so that no one can bypass our app and directly get to pentaho screens they shouldn't be able to reach?

Comment: yes. you can do little research on this. you can directly have to use the same credentials in login so it will directly use those credentials and end user will directly landed up to pentaho login screen.

Comment: The client will have hundreds of users logging in with their own personal enterprise user id.  Are you saying that we will have to use Pentaho's security framework to support this, or not?  Sorry, it's just not clear to me.  In researching this already the answer was not clear.  We need to avoid using Spring Security if at all possible.  thanks again!

Comment: they can use the same credentials in pentaho. the only thing is one has to create those users in pentaho. then we can write xaction and manage this login thing directly from java application.